# Besides Paul, were there any other enemies of the early church who converted to Christianity?

Tags: church-history, new-testament, early-church, church-fathers, conversion

As I was listening to a debate between Drs. William Lane Craig and Richard Carrier on the historicity of Jesus' resurrection, something Dr. Carrier said caught my attention. He claimed that "[Paul] is alone, actually; there's no other enemies of the church that were converted to join the church." I immediately got a hunch that this was unlikely, but I haven't had any luck in finding other antagonists to the early church who were converted.

Based on the New Testament and contemporary (within the 1-200 AD "Early Church" period) historical records, were there any other enemies of the church, aside from Paul, who converted to Christianity?

For reference, the debate can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akd6qzFYzX8), and the point containing the quote starts at 1:28:32.

I would greatly appreciate citations in any answers that you might offer.

To further clarify: I'm not looking for answers from sources that Dr. Carrier would necessarily accept as credible (although citations from extra-biblical, historical sources are definitely encouraged). To place a constraint like that on the question might make it impossible to answer, as he states in the video that he doesn't view the gospels as credible. I would certainly accept answers that reference the gospels.

Also, for the purposes of this question, I would define an "enemy of the church" during the apostolic time period as someone who actively persecutes or opposes Jesus, the apostles, and the early Christian churches.

Comment: Good question... Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your post, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: You could say that the Philippians were once enemies of the church that converted. The story about Paul being in prison and there was an earthquake so the guard was about to commit suicide and Paul stopped him. Hopefully I have that right. But the guard was one persecuting Christians and because of that, he was one of the first Philippians.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! And thanks for asking a fascinating question. While you're here, for a quick overview of this site and what it's all about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). And I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here.

Comment: @NealC Thank you for the example of the jailer from Acts 16! Also, could you elaborate (with references) on your point about the Philippians? Were the people of Philippi generally antagonistic towards Christians, or were there just a few who were angry about the money Paul and Silas cost them by casting the spirit out of the slave girl? Because if they weren't, then the argument would be that all converts to Christianity could be submitted as examples of enemies of the church who converted to join it.

Comment: If the focus is on refuting Carrier, I don't think he would accept the jailer. I also suggest 200 AD is too broad; Carrier would have been talking about the apostolic era.

Comment: Indeed, there's very little that Dr. Carrier does accept as evidence against his view. He totally discounts the gospels as historical documents and attributes Paul's beliefs to mere hallucination. I'd say that the purpose of my question is more to have a ready answer for anyone I might encounter who's read Carrier and his ilk who might make this same claim about Paul being the sole convert from anti-Christian antagonism to Christianity.

Comment: Well, notably there was Constantine, but that was quite a bit later than the apostolic period.

Comment: How are you going to define "enemy"? I don't think this can be objectively answered. Theologically, **everyone** who converted was an enemy.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's exactly the retort that came to mind for me immediately after Dr. Carrier made the claim in the debate, but I guess I'm looking for someone who might be regarded as an active persecutor or opponent of the early Christians. NealC's proposal of the jailer from Acts 16 would be a minimally acceptable example. More examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have edited the question to more clearly define what I mean by "enemy." Thank you for the clarification suggestion!

Comment: Nicodemus is probably an example (John 3).

Comment: It's safe to assume that Nicodemus is an example of this, as he was a leader of the Pharisees and a member of the Jewish ruling council, and those were the same groups that had Him crucified. Thank you for the input, @Flimzy!

Comment: @Jjbroux: And he went to Jesus in secret so that his contemporaries wouldn't know.

Answer (score 8):

In Peter's sermon at Pentecost he accuses the members of his audience of delivering up Jesus to be crucified:

> "Men of Israel, hear these words: Jesus of Nazareth, a man attested
>   to you by God with mighty works and wonders and signs that God did
>   through him in your midst, as you yourselves know—this Jesus,
>   delivered up according to the definite plan and foreknowledge of God,
>   you crucified and killed by the hands of lawless men." (Acts 2:22-23,
>   ESV)

Concluding remarks end on their guilt for crucifying Jesus.

> "Let all the house of Israel therefore know for certain that God has
>   made him both Lord and Christ, this Jesus whom you crucified." (Acts
>   2:36, ESV)

The response of the crowd was to be convicted:

> Now when they heard this they were cut to the heart, and said to
>   Peter and the rest of the apostles, "Brothers, what shall we do?" And
>   Peter said to them, "Repent and be baptized every one of you in the
>   name of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins, and you will
>   receive the gift of the Holy Spirit. For the promise is for you and
>   for your children and for all who are far off, everyone whom the Lord
>   our God calls to himself." And with many other words he bore witness
>   and continued to exhort them, saying, "Save yourselves from this
>   crooked generation." So those who received his word were baptized, and
>   there were added that day about three thousand souls. (Acts 2:37-41,
>   ESV)

Why would a crowd of Jews in close historical proximity to the crucifixion be cut to the heart over an accusation of crucifying Jesus, and repent and be baptized, if they were not in some way involved in the crucifixion itself? The simple answer is that they were involved in the persecution of Jesus, and therefore of early Christianity.

Whether or not this meets the definition of persecuting the early *church* depends on your definitions of "the early church" and "persecution."

But secondarily, what is difficult to prove in specifics is easier in statistics. Rome was not sympathetic to Christianity, and generally did persecute early Christians. And yet, the church achieved explosive growth that took the form of abandoning one's former lifestyle. Are we to believe there was zero overlap between these two groups?

Comment: (+1) Nice answer.  I have shared this in the [special chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26215/new-answers-to-old-questions) for new answers to old questions so that it hopefully won't get overlooked.  Feel free to share your own answers, or those of others that you come across, there in the future.

Comment: @Ben Mordecai: This is another very good point! I would like to see a complete answer incorporating all of the examples discussed in the comments on the initial question as well, for completeness' sake.